# Can I give a single non-sudo user access to run a single command without sudo?

Tags: permissions, sudo, chmod

Is it possible to give a single user without sudo access, the ability to run a sudo protected command like `chmod`?

Comment: This doesn’t answer your question, but I think it’s worth pointing out that allowing a user to run `chmod` as root in one way or another, without filtering what they can do with `chmod`, is effectively equivalent to granting them full root access.

Comment: yeah, is it `chmod`, or something else? Because as Stephen Kitt says, you can't give someone access to `chmod` without effectively allowing them to become root. There's other things that might be safe. Might be worth talking about the problem you're solving, more than about what you consider a good solution at this point!

Comment: What does it mean, "sudo protected"? I can run this command with my credentials.

Comment: why not limit sudo for a specific user to a single command (or even a group of commands) you want him to be able to run ?

Comment: @golder3 That is basically what I want, but how to limit sudo for a specific user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**sudo** configuration files are stored in `/etc/sudoers` file and `/etc/sudoers.d` directory. It is preferable to add a file, **with the same name as the user** you want to set the sudo for, to `/etc/sudoers.d` although you can also edit `/etc/sudoers`.

The basic syntax is **who where = (as_whom) what**

For example:

```
root ALL = (ALL:ALL) ALL
```

menas allow user `root` to run on any host (ALL = ) as any user:group (ALL:ALL) any command (ALL)

In your case, you need to do something like:

```
echo "ltd_user ALL=NOPASSWD:/bin/cat, PASSWD:/bin/chmod" > /etc/sudoers.d/ltd_user
```

This gives user `ltd_user` rights to run `cat` without typing password and `chmod` after typing password, on any host, as any user

After making a file under `/etc/sudoers.d` you should set permission to 440

```
chmod 440 /etc/sudoers.d/ltd_user
```

Also note that I gave a very basic example (and hence used echo and redirection) but it would be good practice to use `visudo` command to edit sudo configuration files, which ensures that only one person is editing the file at a time, has the proper permissions, and refuses to write out the file and exit if there are syntax errors in the changes made.

```
visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/ltd_user
```

see `man sudoers` for more details and advanced examples